# How to convert a COBOL string with implied decimal to decimal type in Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

See I have a COBOL column like this

```
05  AMOUNT      PIC 999V99.
```

Here the `V` means decimal is implied. So value `123.45` will be represented as `12345`

In order to convert it back to `decimal(5,2)` in **Netezza**, I tried the following

```
CAST('12345' AS DECIMAL(5,2))  --This will cause overflow, of course
CAST('12345' AS DECIMAL(5))/100 --Works, but looks awkward
```

Does any one know a better way to convert '12345' back to decimal(5,2) in **Netezza?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use the method of converting it to pack decimal and then to numeric type.
I noticed an extra character is needed when converting to PACKED DECIMAL. The extra character can be any character.

Prefix TOOLKIT.SQLEXT. is where our extension function installed.

```
SELECT  TOOLKIT.SQLEXT.PACKEDDECIMAL2STR(TOOLKIT.SQLEXT.NUM2PACKEDDEC('12345'||' ') ,2)::NUMERIC(5,2);
```

Result:

```
123.45
```

```
SELECT  TOOLKIT.SQLEXT.PACKEDDECIMAL2STR(TOOLKIT.SQLEXT.NUM2PACKEDDEC('-12345'||' ') ,2)::NUMERIC(5,2);
```

Result:

```
-123.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cast(substr(a.field,1,3)||'.'||substr(a.field,4,2) AS DECIMAL(5,2))
from (select '12345' as field) a
```